# How to remove repetetive unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

Let's say I have the following class:

```js
class Foo {
    public a( a, b ) {
        return this._execute( {a,b} );
    }
    
    public b( a ) {
        return this._execute( a );
    }

    private _execute( a ) {
        if ( ...condition... ) {
            throw new Error("Validation failed!"); 
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to prepare a set of unit tests for it. Should I add a test that should check the `condition` both for `a()` and `b()`? Maybe only one method should check it? If so, which one? Or maybe I should use some other approach?

My goal is to reduce the number of unit tests and in this case, I've got the same test for both methods.

Comment: exectute -> execute (cannot edit only 2chars)

Comment: You can unit test `_execute` to verify it works for the correct inputs. Then add unit tests using a spy to check that `a` and `b` call `_execute` with the expected input - no need to test further around this if you *know* `_execute` works and you *know* `a()` and `b()` use it as appropriate.

Comment: I don't want to write a test for the private method.

Comment: Then the only way to guarantee that both `a()` and `b()`  are validating properly is to write tests for each of them that exercise the validation. That's only logical - you cannot verify that they both use the same common validation *and* that the common validation is correct. However, consider using SOLID principles to break up the code - make a validator class that can be injected in `Foo` and then you can test the validator to your heart's content and then make a very simple check that `Foo` uses it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @VLAZ you can copy and paste your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your code into components that are dealing with one thing only:

```
class Foo {
    private _validator;
    
    constructor(validator) {
      this._validator = validator;
    }
    
    public a( a, b ) {
        return this._validator.validate( {a,b} );
    }
    
    public b( a ) {
        return this._validator.validate( a );
    }
}

class MyValidator {
  public validate( value ) {
      if ( /*...condition...*/ ) {
          throw new Error("Validation failed!"); 
      }

      return value;
  }
}
```

Now you can test `MyValidator` as much as you want to make sure it handles inputs as you want. The tests will be applicable for both `Foo#a` and `Foo#b`.

What you want to do next is to verify that the methods *do* use the validator, so in a test setup you can create a mock validator and instantiate `const foo = new Foo( mockValidator )`. Then the test can look like this:

```
test( "a() uses the validator", () => {
    //arrange
    const mockValidator = { validate: jest.fn() };
    const foo = new Foo( mockValidator );
    const value = "something";
    
    //act
    foo.a( value );
    
    //assert
    expect(mockValidator.validate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value);
}

test( "a() does not swallow the validation error", () => {
    //arrange
    const mockValidator = { validate: () => { throw Error("mock") } };
    const foo = new Foo( mockValidator );
    
    //act + assert
    expect(() => foo.a( "" )).toThrow();
}
```

Note: I'm using Jest for illustrative purposes. The same can be achieved using other testing libraries.